# Gatsby site serving on EC2 with pm2 node with aws classic load balancer needs https

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, gatsby, amazon-elb

I am running a Gatsby site in development mode as a dev server on EC2 with a loadbalancer pointing from port 80 to 8000. I have setup a cname on my domain dns to point to the load balancer this works fine. However I need to display this page as an iframe in sanity.io as a web preview and it requires https.

I've read through this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html and most of it is pretty straight forward for the most part.

What I have done so far is created a listener for 443 https on the loadbalancer and added https 443 to the security group. i have succsufully issued a certificate to the subdomain I am using with aws and attached it to the loadbalancer listener.

Gatsby has a article about custom certs for development mode here https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/local-https/#custom-key-and-certificate-files What I am looking for is the cert file, the authority file and the key file in order to pass this command below

Where in the aws certificate manager do I find these files. I think that is the last piece I need to get https working, correct me if I am wrong.

thanks ahead of time.

`gatsby develop --https --key-file ../relative/path/to/key.key --cert-file ../relative/path/to/cert.crt --ca-file ../relative/path/to/ca.crt`

This is the process I used to request my certficate and it says it's issued
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-request-public.html

But how do I use it with the custom https command with gatsby?

There is a export option but it says only for private keys. Do I need to create a private key and then I can export these files I need?

Do I even need to run https on gatsby's side. I watched a video using apache and no change was made to the apache server to get https working with the loadbalancer.

Here is a screenshot of my loadbalancer listenr

[image]

Here is a image of my security groups

[image]

If I run the `--https` for gatsby develop it breaks my site I can no longer visit it via the loadbalancer or port 8000. So not sure what to do here.

Comment: I'm still very confused on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not to encrypt the connection between your ELB and the EC2 instances. If your EC2 instances are not publicly reachable, but only through the load balancer instead, it is best practice to terminate the SSL connection on the load balancer. No need to encrypt HTTP requests inside an AWS VPC (i.e. between ELB and target instances).

> You can create a load balancer that listens on both the HTTP (80) and HTTPS (443) ports. If you specify that the HTTPS listener sends requests to the instances on port 80, the load balancer terminates the requests and communication from the load balancer to the instances is not encrypted. [1]

There is some discussion (e.g. on the blog of Kevin Burke) whether it is necessary to encrypt traffic inside a VPC. [2] However, most people are probably not doing it.

What it means for you: Use the same instance protocol for your targets as before: HTTP via port 8000 for both listeners. Do not set up SSL for your Gatsby service. Use a plain HTTP server config instead. No changes are necessary to ELB targets when using SSL termination on the load balancer.

#### References

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html
[2] https://acloud.guru/forums/aws-certified-security-specialty/discussion/-Ld2pfsORD6ns5dDK5Y7/tlsssl-termination?answer=-LecNy4QX6fviP_ryd7x

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by use a plain HTTP server config instead? How do I then run my gatsby server then? do you mean to setup something like a nginx server pointing to the gatsby server? What does terminate the https connection on the loadbalancer mean? I'm not quite sure what my first step is yet from this answer, despite it being very clear, Im still lost.

Comment: I think you mean for http server config dont use https for gatsby. Ok I had already done that. So what are you saying I should change for the loadbalancer exactly, you mention for both listeners do http, what does that mean exactly. Port 443 to 8000, as http not https?

Comment: Finally understood what you meant. Thanks so much it's working now.